# Continue remaining loop when the operation fails in middle

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a large dataset in `xml` to import in `mysql` database. My code works fine but the problem is that, some invalid description string/character breaks the operation and the loop stops in middle. What i want is, if the loop breaks in some row i want to continue rest. And i tried the `TRY CATCH` and mysql_real_escape_string which doesn't seems to be working properly or may be i put it in wrong way. Any idea Thanks.

```
$imagearray = simplexml_load_file('imagelist.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($imagearray as $image){
    $name = $image->$imgname;
    $description= $image->$description;

    $image = "INSERT INTO `tbl_image` (`imagename`, `imagedescription`) VALUES ( '".$name."', '".$description."')"; 
    $conn->query($image);
}
```

Comment: what did the code look like with try catch? That is the correct way to go

Comment: I simply add it after foreach

$imagearray = simplexml_load_file('imagelist.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($imagearray as $image){
    try{
        $name = $image->$imgname;
        $description= $image->$description;

        $image = "INSERT INTO `tbl_image` (`imagename`, `imagedescription`) VALUES ( '".$name."', '".$description."')"; 
    $conn->query($image);
    }catch(Exception $e){
       continue;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Escape the input/used prepared statements and you won't have issues with the query being broken.

```
$imagearray = simplexml_load_file('imagelist.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($imagearray as $image){
    $name = $image->$imgname;
    $description= $image->$description;

    $image = "INSERT INTO `tbl_image` (`imagename`, `imagedescription`) VALUES ( ?, ?)"; 
    $prep = $conn->prepare($image); //prepare the query
    $prep->bind_param("ss", $name, $description); //bind params
    $prep->execute(); //execute
}
```